# scroll after clicking keeps previous link active

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I couldn't find my solution online after hours and days search. I have made a single page site for my client. My problem is when I click on a link, it smoothly scrolls to page but when I scroll up or down, the clicked link stays active along with scroll spy.

Example: Visit the [demo website](http://www.shahpoojan.com/vs)

click on a link - Reel and then scroll up and down. Reel link will stay active.

Following is my Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.navbar-nav li>a').click(function(){
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        });

        var navpos = $('#nav').offset();
        console.log(navpos.top);
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top) {
                $('#nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            }
            else {
                $('#nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            }
        });

        /* highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs */
        $('body').scrollspy({target: '#nav' })

        /* smooth scrolling for scroll to top */
        $('.scroll-top').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
        });

         /*smooth scrolling for nav sections */
        $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function(e){
            $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').removeClass('active');
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            var posi = $(link).offset().top+2;
            $('body,html').stop().animate({scrollTop:posi},700);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

If I remove "return false;", it flickers when I click on a link before smooth scroll but my problem gets solved. Hoping for a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a fiddle. This would help people having the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is still focused. It is defined on line 92 in your stylesheet:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #f39c12;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

The last comma separated element is (simplified) :

```
a:focus {
    color: #f39c12;
}
```

This makes the link have the color when you clicked it. To remove this you can remove `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus` from line 92 and add this to your stylesheet:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #95a5a6;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}
```